# How to hide index.jsp in url

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

In my java ee project I mapped welcome page as

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

After login correctly I go to `index.jsp`. Which is my home. What I need is hide `index.jsp` in url. Only `localhost://EMS`.

Usually it doesn't show `index.jsp` in url. But sometimes I press back arrow key eventually I go to `http://localhost:8080/EMS/index.jsp`

Is there any way to hide that? I'm not using any java related frameworks at the moment. Also I use apache tomcat.

Comment: After successful Login how are you navigating to index.jsp?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595346/how-to-remove-jsps-native-request-url) similar question

Comment: @NamanGala   response.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); using that

Comment: `Usually it doesn't show index.jsp in url` then what does it show?

Comment: @BackSlash I didn't map index.jsp. Because I never call that in browser. And it is user WebPages folder. No special place. As your answer I don't need any url pattern.

Comment: @NamanGala But sometimes I press back arrow key eventually I go to http://localhost:8080/EMS/index.jsp

Comment: Usually you get `http://localhost:8080/EMS/` or `http://localhost:8080/EMS/Login.jsp`?

Comment: @NamanGala yeah. that is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

See "[Configuring Welcome Files](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/webapp/configurejsp.html#wp157851)".

At the beginning of `index.jsp`, you need to check whether the user is logged in. If not, redirect to `login.jsp`. If you don't want the user to see `login.jsp` in the URL, you need to [include the JSP instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110148/include-another-jsp-file).

If you want to make sure that the user never sees `index.jsp`, you need to check the request URL and redirect to `/` when the URL ends with `/index.jsp` using `response.sendRedirect()`.

Comment: I tried this thing using index control servlet. And that servlet set to welcome-file. After go to servlet if session is not null then go to index.jsp. Which is "/". If session is empty I load back to login. Unfortunately  it gave me a memory leak.

Comment: The approach itself can't result in a memory leak. You have another bug in your code or you're not giving the VM enough memory to begin with. Without additional information, I can't help you.

Comment: Yes it was happened because my project's another stupid buy. You method is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To do so you have to map your JSP file in web.xml file.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>path/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You will be able to access the url `http://localhost:8080/EMS/`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off making index.jsp your welcome page and checking whether a user is logged in, and redirecting to login.jsp from that page.

Comment: Please check the answer I gave to Aaron